# How to read element in list item in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the following output from a function and I need to read shape, labels, and domain from this stream.

```
[Annotation(shape=Rectangle(x=0.0, y=0.0, width=1.0, height=1.0), labels=[ScoredLabel(62282a1dc79ed6743e731b36, name=GOOD, probability=0.5143796801567078, domain=CLASSIFICATION, color=Color(red=233, green=97, blue=21, alpha=255), hotkey=ctrl+3)], id=622cc4d962f051a8f41ddf35)]
```

I need them as follows

```
shp = Annotation.shape
lbl = Annotation.labels
dmn = domain
```

It seems simple but I could not figure it out yet.

Comment: Is that "output" a string of text that you want to parse?

Comment: Where does `domain` come from?

Comment: You could think its as a string. But I don't want to use split or regex here.

Comment: domain is there too."domain=CLASSIFICATION"

Comment: "You could think its as a string" -- but would you be correct if you thought that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `output` as a list of `Annotation` objects:

```
output = [Annotation(...)]
```

you ought to be able to simply do:

```
shp = output[0].shape
lbl = output[0].labels
dmn = labels[0].domain
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what  I was looking for. onot believe that I did not add the []....